# How to use KeyDragZoom in GMAP3?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code is not working:

```
$('#test1').gmap3({action:'get'}).enableKeyDragZoom({
    key: "shift",            
    boxStyle: {
              border: "thick dashed black",
              backgroundColor: "red",
              opacity: 0.5
            },
            paneStyle: {
              backgroundColor: "gray",
              opacity: 0.2
            }
      });
```

Comment: what exactly isn't working? What output do you get?

Comment: it returns Nothing.Actually i need to drag and select a portion of map in gmap3.After selecting the portion i need to zoom in that particular portion.Like  http://gmaps-utility-library-dev.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/keydragzoom/examples/dragzoom.html?packedif any one knows how to solve this then plz reply.its urgent..thnx in advance..